# Where are the top-level attributes of a class stored in Python

Tags: python, class, scope

I would like to understand the following situation:

```
>>> class Test:
...     a = 1
...
>>> x = Test()
>>> x.__dict__
{}
>>> x.a
1
>>> x.__dict__
{}
>>> x.a = 1
>>> x.__dict__
{'a': 1}
```

Where is the `a` attribute stored at the beginning and how come it becomes visible in the `__dict__` only after assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are stored on the class itself:

```
>>> class Test:
...     a = 1
... 
>>> Test.__dict__
{'a': 1, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

Python looks first at the instance attributes, then to the class.

Comment: And why is it that `x.a=1` created an instance attribute instead of changing the class attribute?

Comment: If I say `a = []` in the class, then `x.a.append(2)` will change the class attribute. If now I instantiate a new instance, let's say `y`, `y.a` will be also `[2]`.

Comment: `append` does not change the class attribute, it changes the object referenced by the class attribute. And every instance of the class has the same object, so the contents of the object is the same, too.

Comment: @Moch: don't confuse assignment to an instance attribute with *modifying* a mutable object.

Comment: @Mkoch: and `x.a = 1` is no different from `self.a = 1` inside a method; how else would you set instance attributes?